# Application insights similar analytics capabilities on API Management?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

We have an API hosted in app service behind the API management gateway, with application insights analytics we are able to get quite good understanding of the app service, but wondering a similar tool exists for API Management service? The Analytics tab in publisher portal is too basic.. Thanks

Comment: Have you taken a look at the capabilities to log events to Event Hubs? With very limited impact development-wise, you can route custom events to storage. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-log-event-hubs (slightly outdated in regard to the new portal)

Comment: I did saw that sample, but Microsoft didn't tell much what to do to use the data for analytics, e.g. use similar tool like app insights

Comment: We are working on App Insights integration - if you want more business focused analytics based on log-to-eventhub, we now have a Power BI solution template that builds this all for you. Take a look at http://aka.ms/apimpbi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on it right now! https://aka.ms/apimroadmap